# Chartjs draw line chart where line go back and forth (by chronological order)

Tags: jquery, django, charts, dataset, chart.js

So I want to draw a line chart where the line goes from point to point by chronological order but points can go back and forth so the line would have to go all directions not only right. I don't really know if this is possible but I haven't find any solution so far.

I initialize a new line chart with null data and I pass through ajax a list of players (datasets) and each of them has a list of points with x and y in chronological order. For example:

```
data = {
    "labels": [3,4,5],
    "default": [[15,2],[25,0],[45,1]],
    "players": ["Max Ros"]
}
return Response(data)
```

The default data list have the first element as the Y value and the second as the label position it belongs to. In this case the value 15 belongs to the label in the 2nd position, which means the number 5 in the xaxis.

I am now able to draw all the points to each dataset but the line follows the xaxis label order and not the one which I inserted the points.

My code is the following:

```
$.ajax({
    'method':'GET',
    'url': url,
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        chart = new Chart($('#myChart'), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: data.labels,
                datasets: []
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fixedStepSize: 10,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                },
            }
        });
        data.players.forEach( function(a, i) {
            console.log(a);
            chart.data.datasets.push({
                label: a,
                data: [null],
                showLine: true,
                spanGaps: true
            });
            data.default[i].forEach( function(e, j) {
                console.log(e);
                chart.data.datasets[i].data[e[1]] = e[0];
            });
        });
        chart.update();
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
});
```

**The result I get now**

[image: The result I get now]

**The result I want**

[image: The result I want]

Hope someone knows how to solve it in case it is possible or maybe suggest another tool where it can be possible. Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Please Add a screenshot (It is very difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve) + It's better to add code snippet https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @EzraSiton I have already added the screenshots about my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using string values on the x-axis...

```
        labels: ['0', '1', '2'],
        datasets: [{
          label: data.players[0],
          data: [{x: '2', y: 15}, {x: '0', y: 25}, {x: '1', y: 45}]
        }]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Chart($('#myChart'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['0', '1', '2'],
            datasets: [{
              label: 'Max Ros',
              data: [{x: '2', y: 15}, {x: '0', y: 25}, {x: '1', y: 45}]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fixedStepSize: 10,
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }],
            },
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem was not the string, because with the previous code also works, but the two scripts you added. I have no idea what they do or why I didn't have them, but now it works!